# Add Date In Datagridview Current Cell on Keyboard Key Press

Tags: vb.net

How to Add Add Date In Datagridview Current Cell on Keyboard Key Press in vb

My Code

```
        Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        KeyPreview = True
    End Sub
 Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        'when you press the Enter key,invoke the method( you can remove it)
        If Keys.S And Convert.ToString(DataDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value) = ("S".ToString) Then
            'add the code about changing the data
            DataDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = vbNullString
            DataDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = TimeOfDay
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Not Working....

When i Write S in Cell 4 Then Dateandtime Not Add

Comment: do you **really** want that to run everytime the user presses "S" anywhere on any control on the form???

Comment: When i Write S in Cell 4 Then Dateandtime Not Add